# Generate a Graphic PDF dynamically?

Tags: graphics, pdf-generation, photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I want to send a postcard to all my email subscribers, that will be designed in some tool, probably like Illustrator or Photoshop.

The postcard should include the name of each recipient, for example in some beveled special font. eventually it should be something that is generated dynamically, in a PDF format.

How can I do this? what is the framework?

Answer (score 0):

there is no option in Photoshop/illustrator for auto generating graphic content. but i know some auto builders for newsletters, email templates.. those are premium services.

> sample premium email templates and newsletters - [see
>   here](https://elements.envato.com/items?categories=Email%20Templates)

if you think you can find some free email template builders. find out.!

> builder example [click here](http://www.maesto.net/themebuilder/demo/builder.html?tpl=Rigo&storefront=envato-elements)

Comment: I'm not looking for the service though, I'm looking for the technique...

Answer (score 0):

There is no option in Photoshop/illustrator for dynamic pdf. instead of using graphic suite, try mail merge option in outlook or use gmail

here is tutorial you can use for bunch of subscribers [(Tutorial)](http://www.labnol.org/internet/personalized-mail-merge-in-gmail/20981/)

i hope it will help.